# Error : expected identifier or '(' before 'volatile'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I tried compiling a code to modify addresses and got an error. Here is the initial part of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


#define FATAL do { fprintf(stderr, "Error at line %d, file %s (%d) [%s]\n",__LINE__, __FILE__, errno,    strerror(errno)); exit(1); } while(0)
#define MAP_SIZE 4096UL
#define MAP_MASK (MAP_SIZE - 1)

void GenerateDelay(int val);

int main(void) {
    int fd;
    int *map_base_c,*map_base_d, *map_base_p, *virt_addr;
    off_t target;
    off_t rTCF0,rTCON,rTCNTB0,rTCMPB0,rTCNTO0;  // The error is at this line (115)

    rTCFG0  =  0x51000000;  //Timer 0 configuration
    rTCON   =  0x51000008;  //Timer rTCON
    rTCNTB0 =  0x5100000c;  //Timer count buffer 0
    rTCMPB0 =  0x51000010;  //Timer compare buffer 0    
    rTCNTO0 =  0x51000014;  //Timer count observation 0
    return 0;
}
```

The error that it shows is

```
pwmTry.c: In function 'main':
pwmTry.c:115: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'volatile'
pwmTry.c:115: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
```

I've indicated in the code which is line 115
I don't understand what is wrong with the code - and I've gotten this error many times before, I just had to delete the offending line. here though, the error is in the declaration and so I can't delete it.

I had written another code that looked pretty much the same and compiled with no errors. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FATAL do { fprintf(stderr, "Error at line %d, file %s (%d) [%s]\n",__LINE__, __FILE__, errno, strerror(errno)); exit(1); } while(0)
#define MAP_SIZE 4096UL
#define MAP_MASK (MAP_SIZE - 1)

void GenerateDelay(int val);

int main(void) {
    int fd;
    int *map_base_c,*map_base_d, *map_base_p, *virt_addr;

    off_t target,control,data,pullup;

    //following the configuration order of setting 
    //1. Data register
    //2. Control register
    //3. Pullup register
    control=0x56000010;
    data   =0x56000014; 
    pullup =0x56000018;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: What OS/compiler? Can you look at preprocessed code to see what exactly was expanded? From the description of an error, it may seem that `off_t` isn't exactly type but some macro.

Comment: What is off_t ? Are you sure you can define variables of this type in one line with commas ?

Comment: I have done the same thing before with no problems, I have used off_t and defined many variables in one line with commas. The error came in the other code when I tried to define another variable after this, but in that code when I deleted the offending line, the code looked pretty much exactly like this one. 

My compiler is arm-linux-gcc-4.3.2

Comment: Once again, look at preprocessed code. After second example though it is more likely that `rTCF0` and friends are macros on your system. Impossible to be sure without this after-pp code, of course.

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org

Comment: I checked off_t, I have the type definition in the header file <sys/types.h> so no worries there. ( I had included <sys/types.h> in the code that I compiled, I forgot to show it here)

Comment: okay, thank you, keltar! I did the following: 

    arm-linux-gcc-4.3.2 -E pwmTry.c

And found out that the names rTCON etc. had been defined elsewhere as macros. Therein lay the problem. 

This is a rather valuable tip, thank you!

Comment: @user3691157: You might like to add this as an answer to your own question and then even ccept this answer. This shows SO and its users that the issue had ben solved.

Answer (score 3):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646451/error-expected-identifier-or-before-volatile#comment38203891_24646451) by keltar made it possible to find the problem.

I did the following:

> arm-linux-gcc-4.3.2 -E pwmTry.c

And found out that the names `rTCON` etc. had been defined elsewhere as macros. Therein lay the problem.

This is a rather valuable tip, thank you!